# Scala Play 2.5 How to make Java's Context/Session/Request accessible to a view?

Tags: scala, playframework, play-authenticate

I'm working on this Scala [play-authenticate-usage-scala](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala) project where I build on top of a Java framework [play-authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate) (I know, life is not perfect ...). While running the application I see the exception included below.

Carefully inspecting the stack trace leads me to the view `views._providerPartial.scala.html` that is using the `forProviders.scala.html` template that in turns uses classes that depend on Java's Play `play.mvc.Http.{ Session, Context, etc}` and thus, the error because my sample application brings the Scala `play.api.mvc._` ones.

I know I can do in Scala:

```
import play.core.j.JavaHelpers

val jContext : play.mvc.Http.Context = JavaHelpers.createJavaContext(request)
val jSession : play.mvc.Http.Session = context.session()
```

The question is how can I make these above implicitly available to that view.

```
[error] application - 

! @72ef8b5j8 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/login] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.
    at play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:62)
    at play.mvc.Http$Context$Implicit.session(Http.java:330)
    at com.feth.play.module.pa.views.html.forProviders_Scope0$forProviders$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(forProviders.template.scala:37)
    at com.feth.play.module.pa.views.html.forProviders_Scope0$forProviders$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(forProviders.template.scala:35)
    at play.twirl.api.TemplateMagic$.defining(TemplateMagic.scala:13)
    at com.feth.play.module.pa.views.html.forProviders_Scope0$forProviders.apply(forProviders.template.scala:35)
    at views.html._providerPartial_Scope0$_providerPartial.apply(_providerPartial.template.scala:38)
    at views.html.login_Scope0$login_Scope1$login.apply(login.template.scala:74)
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Application.scala:57)
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Application.scala:57)
```

**UPDATE** I attempted the following but didn't work. Basically Java side expects all these in a `ThreadLocal`. The specific `ThreadLocal` instance is publicly located in `play.mvc.Http.Context.current`. Therefore I prepared a template helper called `_adaptScalaToJava.scala.html` like this:

```
@import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala._
@import play.core.j.JavaHelpers

@()(implicit request: AuthenticatedRequest[Any])

@play.mvc.Http.Context.current.set(JavaHelpers.createJavaContext(request))
```

it sets directly the jContext in the current thread and is used like this:

```
@_adaptScalaToJava
@forProviders(playAuth, skipCurrent) { p =>
    <li>
    @if(p.getKey() == "openid") {
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="askOpenID('@p.getUrl()');">
    } else {
        <a href="@p.getUrl()">
    }
    @_providerIcon(p.getKey())</a>
    </li>
}
```

but even though compiles find it still fires the same exception ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing only this line before the troubling code solves the issue:

```
@play.mvc.Http.Context.current.set(play.core.j.JavaHelpers.createJavaContext(request))
@forProviders(playAuth, skipCurrent) { p =>
```

trying to make it a bit more clean i.e. that it isn't reset all the time, it is still a mystery for me why this won't work:

```
@if (play.mvc.Http.Context.current.get() == null) { 
    @play.mvc.Http.Context.current.set(play.core.j.JavaHelpers.
         createJavaContext(request)) 
}
```

Seems like the `play.mvc.Http.Context.current` is not `null` ... bottom line is I need to connect with the IDE and debug the code.

**UPDATE** Actually this is the official way to do it:

```
@play.core.j.JavaHelpers.withContext(request) { jContext =>
    @forProviders(playAuth, skipCurrent) { p =>
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That may work, but that's not the official way to do it -- JavaHelpers is not a part of Play's public API and may change without warning.

Comment: and what is the official way to support Scala mixed Java <-> Scala apps? In my case I want to use Scala but can't live without a Java plugin

Comment: You should set up a Java controller and then call out to Scala code from there

Comment: Thank you for the comments, it is really useful! I have the app in a state that works but of course want it to be the best possible maintainance-wise ... good idea to implement those affected controllers into Java. Now after playing with Play for quite a while I still think that there should be better and more transparent support for mixed Scala-Java apps. I prefer to write Scala 10x more than Java and should not be forced by any framework to use a specific language. If play had a common base abstract layer and smooth implicit conversion there would not be need for a `play.core.j.JavaHelpers`

Comment: I also think that there isn't any fundamental reason why the main play abstraction (Context, Request, Session, Flash, Messages, Form, etc) shouldn't share a common base or even be of the same type. I understand that one uses `implicit` while the other `ThreadLocal` to pass stuff around but still ...with so many plugins around done in either Java or Scala, we shouldn't be bumping into walls all the time.

Comment: Refactoring this is a major part of Play 3.0, which is why I mention  it.

Comment: Excellent good to know! I isolate my use of the `play.core.j.JavaHelpers` to be ready for a smoother migration! Looking forward to it :)